# Nuxt ssr asyncData axios request not works on page reload

Tags: docker, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

After 5-6 hours of searching for the solution, I start to give up. I have a project with docker, node & nuxt.I would like to share meta tags on FB and for this, I need SSR && vue-meta and for vue-meta I need asyncData.

it works with different api!

```
async asyncData({ params, $axios, error }) {
  const product = await $axios.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/1`);
  return { product };
},
```

It is working when i navigate to here with nuxt routing, but if i reload the page (just here) then i get a RuntimeError from the nuxt ssr.

SO THE REAL PROBLEM IS I GET A RuntimeError ON PAGE RELOAD ON LOCALHOST

```
async asyncData({ params, $axios, error }) {
  //axios knows the api
  //http://localhost:8080/ 
  const product = await $axios.$get(`products/${params.id}`);
  return { product };
},
```

If I try this with Axios then I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

If I try this with @nuxt/http then I get this error

```
request to http://localhost:8080/products/some-id failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I think the problem is when I push hard reload on this page, then I cannot make requests on localhost but I don't know why and how to solve it.

my nuxt-config.js

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode)
  // ssr: false,

  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap' },
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/styles.scss',
    // '~node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    // '~node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/notifier',
    '~/plugins/axios',
    '~/plugins/dateFilter',
    '~/plugins/loading',
  ],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    'nuxt-lazysizes', //https://github.com/ivodolenc/nuxt-lazysizes
    '@aceforth/nuxt-optimized-images', //https://github.com/juliomrqz/nuxt-optimized-images //only build
  ],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    'nuxt-i18n',
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxt/http',
  ],

  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      // './assets/scss/*.scss',
      '@/assets/scss/_variables.scss',
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss',
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss',
      '@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss',
    ]
  },

  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false,
    icons: false,
  },

  axios: {
    // baseURL: ``, //built by docker compose from API_PORT && API_HOST variables
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: false,
          user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' },
        },
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/admin/products',
    },
  },

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
    // babel: {
    //   compact: true,
    // },
  },

  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(
        {
          name: 'product-edit',
          path: '/admin/products/edit/:id',
          component: 'pages/admin/products/add.vue',
        },
        {
          name: 'product-image-upload',
          path: '/admin/products/product-image-upload/:id',
          component: 'pages/admin/products/product-image-upload.vue',
        },
        {
          name: 'gallery-image-upload',
          path: '/admin/gallery-image-upload',
          component: 'pages/admin/gallery-image-upload.vue',
        },
      );
    }
  },

  env: {
    baseUrl: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
    imagePath: `${process.env.BASE_URL}:${process.env.API_PORT}/uploads`,
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
    imagePath: `${process.env.BASE_URL}:${process.env.API_PORT}/uploads`,
  },

  loading: '~/components/LoadingBar.vue',

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      { code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en.js' },
      { code: 'hu', iso: 'hu-HU', file: 'hu.js' },
      { code: 'de', iso: 'de-DE', file: 'de.js' },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: '/i18n/',
    parsePages: false,
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
    },
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
    },
    seo: false,
    vueI18nLoader: true,
    strategy: 'no_prefix',
  },

  lazySizes: {
    extendAssetUrls: {
      img: 'data-src',
      source: 'data-srcset',
      // Component with custom props
      AppImage: ['source-md-url', 'image-url'],
    },
  },

  optimizedImages: {
    inlineImageLimit: 1000,
    handleImages: ['jpeg', 'png', 'svg', 'webp', 'gif'],
    optimizeImages: false,
    optimizeImagesInDev: false,
    defaultImageLoader: 'img-loader',
    mozjpeg: {
      quality: 80,
    },
    optipng: {
      optimizationLevel: 3,
    },
    pngquant: false,
    gifsicle: {
      interlaced: true,
      optimizationLevel: 3,
    },
    svgo: {
      // enable/disable svgo plugins here
    },
    webp: {
      preset: 'default',
      quality: 75,
    },
  },
};
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
    env_file: .env
    expose:
      - $SERVER_PORT
    ports:
      - $SERVER_PORT:$SERVER_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      NUXT_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      NUXT_PORT: $CLIENT_PORT
      API_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      API_PORT: $SERVER_PORT
      BASE_URL: $BASE_URL
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - $CLIENT_PORT
    ports:
      - $CLIENT_PORT:$CLIENT_PORT
```

Update: if I start my nuxt project without Docker then everything works fine but this is not a solution for me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my question. I had to use nginx proxy as a container and some nuxt config.

```
  // https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: 'http://nginx/api' // name of the docker proxy
    }
  },
```